# Find for all value of constant $a>0$; the interval of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+a^{n}}x^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

*Find for all value of constant $a>0$; the interval of convergence of the power series
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+a^{n}}x^{n}$.*

What I have tried is; if we let $b_{n}=\frac{1}{1+a^{n}}x^{n}$ so we get by the Ratio test

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\left | b_{n+1} \right |}{\left | b_{n} \right |}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left | x \right |\frac{\frac{1}{a^n} + 1}{\frac{1}{a^n} + a}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\left | x \right | \frac{1}{a}& \mathrm{if} \ \frac{1}{a}<1\\ 
\left | x \right | & \mathrm{if} \ \frac{1}{a}\geq 1
\end{matrix}\right.$

So the radius of convergence we get

$r=\left\{\begin{matrix}
a & \mathrm{if} \  \frac{1}{a}<1 \\ 
1 & \mathrm{if} \ \frac{1}{a}\geq 1
\end{matrix}\right.$

Now what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Therefore, the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+a^{n}}x^{n}$ is convergent for $|x| < a$ if $a>1$ and for $|x|<1$ in the case $a\leqslant{1}.$ Can you check convergence for $|x|=a, \;\; a>1$ and for $|x|=1 \text{ if } a\leqslant{1}?$

Comment: Yes. They both converge.

Comment: Why they converge? Consider case $a>1.$ If $|x|=a$ then $\dfrac{|x|^n}{1+a^n}=\dfrac{a^n}{1+a^n}=\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{1}{a^n}}\;\;\underset{n\to\infty}\to\;\;{1},$ so necessary convergence condition is not satisfied.
In the case $a\leqslant{1}$ (and $|x|=1$) the situation is similar, since $\dfrac{|x|^n}{1+a^n}=\dfrac{1}{1+a^n}\;\;\underset{n\to\infty}\to\;\;{1}.$

Comment: Oops. You are right. I recalled that this ratio test converges if the 'answer' is lesser than 1. But if they converge to 1, the test still doesn't tell anything about the convergence of the series. Do we have to forget it or?

Comment: I mean a _necessary condition_ for convergence, not the ratio test.

Comment: Ok. So I have to answer this problem, its interval of convergence is $[-1, 1]$ if $a\leq$ and $[-a,a]$ if $a>1$. Am I right?

Comment: No. The series _diverges_ at the endpoints in both cases since general term of the series does not tend to zero as $n\to\infty.$

Comment: Could you please tell me what the answer would be or what the solution is without telling me what/how you did? It would be very helpful for me so that I would do it on my own.

Comment: 1. Case $a>1.$  The series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+a^{n}}x^{n}$ converges for $x\in (-a,\ a).$    
2. Case $a\leqslant{1}.$ The series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+a^{n}}x^{n}$ converges for $x\in (-1,\ 1).$